# Create responsive div element

Tags: css, html

I don't know if the title is quite correct, but what I want basically is to create a div element that stays proportional to the resolution of the screen. For example, if the width is 1900px I want that the div have:

```
width: 1115px;
height: 775px;
```

But if the width of the page is 1050px I want:

```
width: 620px;
height: 430px;
```

What should be my CSS to allow this?

So I want that the width is a percentage of the screen, let's say, and the height is based on the width.

Comment: Do you mean set those sizes using `media queries`? Or you want them to always size and retain their aspect ratio?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I want that div to mantain the aspect ratio. Those 2 were just an example, if the width is something between 1050 and 1900, I want that div to keep proportional. I think is possible to set a width to the container, then the div width is a percentage of that container (parent). But for the height I also want to be a percentage of the width div

Comment: looks like : div {width:60%;height:40vw;} .... which is your average ratio here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions to make the element proportional to the screen, one which depends on your setup.

You can use percentage

```
width: 20%;
```

But this only defines a percentage of the parent element, and does not make both your width and height proportional

You can also use [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). This defines a percentage of the viewport. If you use viewport width `vw` you can get a height which is dependent on the width.

```
height: 10vw; /*10% of viewport width*/
width: 10vw;
```

You do have to be aware that this is relatively new, so do not forget to check "known issues" on caniuse.com

---

You can also setup media queries to handle smaller or bigger screens.

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {/*10% of 300px is very small, so we change it to 90%*/
 .selector {
   width: 90vw;
 }
}
```

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, don't forget to check [known issues for Viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) on Can I use...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, simply you should calculate the desired aspect ratio, i.e. width/height:

[Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), like this:

```
.selector {
  width: 1115px;
  heigth: 775px;
}

@media (max-width: 1050px) {
 .selector {
   width: 620px;
   height: 430px;
 }
}
```

Comment: that way what I would have 2 different sizes depending if the width is less or more then 1050px, but want I want is that the div is resized automatically for "every" width. Basically I want to create an auto resizable div.

Comment: So then, you can combine media queries with `vw` and `vh` units as described below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38544705/6627212